# How do you get get more performance out of BufWriter in rust

Tags: c, rust, io, buffer

I was trying to recreate GNUs yes (mostly for its ridiculous output speed) in rust.
It achieves this by buffering output into a page aligned buffer and then writing it all at once. Here is my implementation of [GNUs yes in c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/yes.c)

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define LEN 2
#define TOTAL 8192
int main() {
    char yes[LEN] = {'y', '\n'};
    char *buf = malloc(TOTAL);
    int bufused = 0;
    while (bufused < TOTAL) {
        memcpy(buf+bufused, yes, LEN);
        bufused += LEN;
    }
    while(write(1, buf, TOTAL));
    return 1;
}
```

This gives a ridiculous output speed (measured through a pipe) of around

`$ ./a.out | pv > /dev/null`

`39.0GiB 0:00:12 [3.63GiB/s] [            <=>                                                            ]`

I tried doing this in rust with `BufWriter` like so:

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufWriter, Write};
fn main() {
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let handle = stdout.lock();
    let mut writer = BufWriter::with_capacity(8192,handle);
    let mut w = 0;
    loop {
        writer.write(b"y\n").unwrap();
    }
}
```

which gives me a speed of

`$ cargo run --release | pv > /dev/null`

`57GiB 0:00:04 [ 751MiB/s] [      <=>                                                                  ]`

this is not an issue if I buffer my writes like how I did it in c like so:

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufWriter, Write};

fn main() {
    let mut buffer :[u8;8192] = [0;8192];
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let handle = stdout.lock();
    let mut writer = BufWriter::with_capacity(8192,handle);
    let mut w = 0;

    while w < buffer.len() {
        buffer[w] = 'y' as u8;
        w += 1;
        buffer[w] = '\n' as u8;
        w += 1;
    }
    loop {
        writer.write(&buffer).unwrap();
    }
}
```

which gives me exactly the same speed as c

`$ cargo run --release | pv > /dev/null`

`82GiB 0:00:03 [4.28GiB/s] [    <=>                                                              ]`

so is there any way to do the buffering in `BufWriter` or will I have to manually do it like in c?

Comment: If you _really_ want to optimize throughput on Linux, I suggest taking a look at [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236630).

Comment: In your first Rust implementation, you are copying `y\n` to the buffer repeatedly all through the loop. In your C implementation and your second Rust implementation, you only fill the buffer once at the beginning then output the same buffer repeatedly in the main loop.

Comment: @Jmb isnt that the point of BufWriter?? to do the buffering for me?? i did this change but it still wont change the speed [code](https://pastebin.com/twF8KW24)

Comment: @Jmb I think that's the point of the question: the first snippet shows idiomatic use of `BufWriter` which also happens to slow tihngs down. The question is if it's possible to keep using `BufWriter` normally (perhaps with a performance tweak), but retain C-like speed. I think the problem is also in stdout's line buffering, and not (just) in `BufWriter`, and am somewhat surprised that the OP is getting speed exceeding C with the last snippet.

Comment: But that's the point: the original C code keeps reusing the same pre-filled buffer. The first Rust code repeatedly re-fills the the buffer. You would get a similar difference in C using `fwrite (stdout, 1, 2, "y\n");` (which is buffered too) in the main loop.

Comment: @user4815162342 nah the speed averages out at around 4GB/s in both of them, rust was just faster than c at the time i took that screenshot

Comment: @Jmb so could you possibly show how youd do it in rust while still using BufWriter like how its supposed to be used

Comment: You don't. In the same way that your C code is not using the automatic buffering that C can provide, any Rust code that targets maximum speed _for this specific use case_ must use custom buffering.

Comment: @Jmb that makes sense, but then whats the point of `BufWriter::with_capacity()` ??

Comment: @yaxleypeaks The point is specifying buffer size for all the cases where you _don't_ always write the same thing in a loop.

Comment: As a side note, neither buffers are page-aligned, `malloc` typically allocates with a 16-byte alignment, and rust's allocator could allocate with an alignment as low as one for a byte array (although in practice it's probably also a 16-byte alignment).

Comment: @Aiden4 so without using malloc, [this](https://pastebin.com/E7m2ju4i) code isn't any more performant either. why is that?

Comment: @yaxleypeaks stack variables aren't any more likely to be page-aligned than what `malloc` returns in either c or rust. The only guarantee you'll get is that it will be sufficiently aligned for the type.  The best way to get a page-aligned buffer is rust is a newtype wrapper around an array with a `#[repr(align = "4096")]` tacked on. C compilers provide a similar attribute for structs, although I am less familiar with that side of things.

Comment: @Aiden4 right, that makes sense. [this](https://pastebin.com/t1CAXpSj) does give slightly better performance. thank you :D

Comment: Note that the whole point of `BufWriter` is to automatically aggregate small writes into larger ones. This improves performance for small writes but incurs a slight overhead. In your case you might get slightly better performances by skipping the `BufWriter` since you always write large buffers at once.

Comment: To complement jmb's explanation: the goal of `BufWriter` is to aggregate multiple "userland" writes into a single large `write(2)` (or equivalent) syscall, because syscalls are expensive. It has nothing to do with reusing the buffer's content, indeed `BufWriter` has no support whatsoever for repeatedly writing itself, that's not the point, and it should automatically bypass itself when performing "large" writes.

Comment: @Masklinn that makes sense, thank you :DD